# Git push not triggering jenkins build

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have done a set up to explore more on jenkins and git integration.

I have my repositories on Github and then am trying to automatically trigger a build on jenkins(running on my loacal system on a tomcat with the plugins for git and git hub) on a push from my local repo to the git hub repo.

So far I have explored a few things and below is one of the approach that I could successfully implement.
1. Polling the github repo every minute and when there is push detected the jenkins build is getting triggered.

But what I am trying to establish and still unsuccessful is to implement the jenkins build on git push through webhooks. 
I went through a lot of the knowledge present over internet but still could not make it happen.

1. Also I have created a prsonal token on git hub but am not getting how to use that token on jenkins
   One more point I am trying to do this behind a proxy.
2. On jenkins under the git server config it says to choose credentials but when i add one it does not come under the dropdown for me to select and hence always clicking on verify credentials is not yielding any result.
   I also tried to convert the user name and password to tokens but that also did not work and gives a an error cannot convert to token.

and the github webhook log says : polling not yet started.

Can anyone please give me  the steps for the above?

Below is what I have tried till now
I have put the url in the below format for the payload url
and then tried a push but it did not trigger anything on the jenkins side.
payload url: http://myip:8080/jenkins/github-webhook/

It always displays a red triangle for the deliveries.

It has been a week that I am struck with the same issue. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: If you expands the details of the "red triangle" hook delivery attempt, what does it say? Is your hook URL `http://myip:8080/...` accessible from the public internet, or is it behind a firewall? So long as it's reachable, you don't need to do any other special config.

Comment: On expanding the red triangle it displays the details with the URLs and other things which I vl be able to paste here tomorrow.

And how to check if hook URL is accessible from public internet?

Yes I am behind a proxy.

Also when I poll every minute it works...does that confirm the URL is accessible from public internet.

Thanks for looking into the query Christopher.

Answer (score 0):

Once I failed with the hook when pushing from eclipse with egit plugin. But it perfectly worked with the git bash, Try this if you are using your IDE to push changes.